# How can I get the server-side chart from json

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a string json for example:

`{"records":[{"x":"02.04.2013","y":31.1093},{"x":"30.03.2013","y":31.0834},{"x":"29.03.2013","y":30.9962}]}`.

How can I get a chart on the server side using Java in an environment app engine?

Comment: What do you mean by "chart"? Like an actual graphical chart?

Comment: yes, I have a page like http://www.rfrate.com/#!USD, I need a server-side form the same and send by mail to the format jpg or png

Answer (score 0):

use highchart api .please check it http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: What tools on the server I get a jpg file or png from json

Comment: With highcharts.com chart formed on the client, I need on the server, which would then be stored in a jpg or png format

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell - you can't. AFAIK all java imaging libraries use `java.awt.*` classes which are not available on App Engine.